# Microsoft Teams Channel membership export

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying below script to export all teams channels and their membership type. However, it errors out.

```
{}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Body $body
$accessToken = $response.access_token

# Set the authorization header
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}

# Get all teams in the tenant
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
$teams = $response.value

# Create a list to store the output data
$outputData = @()

# Iterate over each team
foreach ($team in $teams) {
    $teamId = $team.id
    $teamName = $team.displayName

    # Get the channels for the current team
    $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$teamId/channels"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
    $channels = $response.value

    # Iterate over each channel
    foreach ($channel in $channels) {
        $channelId = $channel.id
        $channelName = $channel.displayName

        # Create a custom object to store the data for the current channel
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Team Name" -Value $teamName
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Channel Name" -Value $channelName
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Membership Type" -Value $channel.membershipType

        # Add the custom object to the output data list
        $outputData += $obj
    }
}

# Export the output data to a CSV file
$outputData | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Done! The membership type of all channels has been exported to '$outputFile'."

}
```

Error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
> Found. At line:40 char:17

I understand that its failing at

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$teamId/channels"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
```

Tried using graphexpolrer to verify if this can be done. The url gives the channel details and the membershiptype . However when tried to script using different combination it fails. Even when provided through a CSV file the channle information cant be pulled further. Any pointers would be appreciated.

reference use - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling Graph *directly* from PowerShell, I'd strongly recommend using the PowerShell library specially built for this - it's *much* easier to use for connecting and for sending and receiving typed objects instead of raw json (it's wrapping all that for you).

See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0